# Rotation on UILabel causes weird clipping problems

Tags: cocoa, uikit, uilabel, cgaffinetransform

I have UIButtons, for which I want to rotate the title labels like this:

```
button.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(button.titleLabel.transform, 12*M_PI/180)
```

The result looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKJMM.jpg (Layer borders for clarification)

clipsToBounds is off for both the button and its label and I have tinkered with pretty much any combination of Autoresizing, Autoresize-masks, enlarging the frame, etc. but literally nothing changes about the way that label is drawn.

Any idea on how I can enlarge the label enough?